# what is the difference between ADT and Android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, adt

Simple question: what is the difference between Android Developement Tools and Android Standard Developement Kit? I mean, they're both some usefull tools to develop an Android application.

Correct me if I'm wrong, ADT is about the usefull code stuff, for exemple the libreries, packages... and SDK is actually about the tools: for exemple Debuging.

I know it's kinda stupid, but I've never had this question in mind till today.
Thank you

Comment: Actually it's the other way around

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121178/what-is-the-difference-between-some-android-development-sdk-tools
maybe this will help you find out, where is the difference

Comment: Software Development Kit, not Standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ADT is the Android Developer Tools plugin for Eclipse.

The Android SDK contains the tools and related files necessary to build an Android application. The ADT plugin for Eclipse uses the SDK tools as part of its work.