# Android Studio Cannot Install Any SDK (Im Beginner)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, sdk

Im starting Android Programming so Im installing Android Studio.

When Im trying to run the wizard, I get an error: "Missing SDK"

[image: Missing SDK Error image]

I didn't download any SDK and I know that Android Studio can download and install SDK's itself.

Then, I click on Next to see what's happening:

[image: Wizard To Do Page]

I know this page should has a Todo list to download SDK's and it will download and install them if I click on "Next" Button.

Then, I click on "Next" and sadly I see this page:

[image: Wizard Todo Page (Summary)]

So Why??! It should has a list of SDK's to download! but it hasn't!

If I click on "Finish" button, it should download and install SDK's normally, but it says "Nothing to do!" :(

[image: Wizard Error Page]

I know I never downloaded SDK's! "Android SDK is up to date."??

Then, I looked for emulator and I downloaded it from developer.android.com original website.

[emulator archive page of developer.android.com website](https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive)

I extracted downloaded zipped file into C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk and I tried again.

I didn't see many differences, except in these pages:

[image: Difference in Todo list]

(a warning in bottom)

[image: Difference in finish page]

(error fixed)

Sadly, I have the same problem yet.

Then, When I click on "Finish" button at last page (or when I close the Wizard Page any time) Program sends me to the Android Studio's Main Page! But I can't make a new project:

[image: SDK Problem in the Android Studio's Main Page]

Then, I open the SDK Manager to fix this problem. So I will see another problem!! :(

[image: SDK Manager]

Then, I click on Edit button to fix this problem:

[image: SDK Manager Edit Page]

It sends me to the previous page!!!! :|

You know that I dont have any SDK:

[image: Sdk folder in File Explorer]

And I really don't know that why Android Studio says "Android SDK is up to date." :(

Can anyone help me please?

(As you can see, Im using Windows 11 in a x64 based cpu.)

Comment: I don't know how to solve this for sure, but that's a checkbox next to `Android SDK` in your *SDK Components Setup* screen - and that's checked on my working installation. Have you tried checking it and then doing *Next*?

Comment: Yes, but it has been disabled and I CAN'T check it...

Comment: Hey! Seems like an Android studio bug, haha. Maybe you could try to install the needed SDK platform from a command tool to your mentioned folder? Take a look here https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager. 
Usually you don't need to use it because you have a GUI version of SDK manager, but due to this strange issue it will be fine to use a fallback

Comment: Why don't you remove Android Studio and any SDK that you might have accidentally installed (I know, you have not installed it, but it's worth fact-checking anyway) and start the process from scratch again?

Comment: I started this process from scratch too many times! I remove Android Studio with "Revo Uninstaller Pro" to be sure that there isn't any leftover files from Android Studio... (Where to check if a SDK installed accidentally?)

Comment: @PineapplePie, I installed sdkmanager command tool, and when I use ```sdkmanager --list```, I see this error: ```Error: Could not determine SDK root.```, with: ```Error: Either specify it explicitly with --sdk_root= or move this package into its expected location: <sdk>\cmdline-tools\latest\``` in next line.

Comment: @MHSarmadi --list is showing you the installed SDKs and you have zero, so the error is logical.
Try to install with:     sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-31"

Answer (score 0):

To download Android SDK, you should use a VPN or set DNS.

Comment: Hi Matin! :) I use them now... but it's not working...

Comment: Can you send me a link to download SDK's Manually, please?

Comment: With a good one, you can download SDK. I recommend that you use a VPN service like Windscribe or configure Shecan.ir DNS.
You can find a link on soft98.ir for downloading manually.

Comment: I tried Both Shecan.ir DNS Service and a VPN (I use Kerio Maker VPN Provider) and when I search in soft98.ir website for SDK, Ill only find "SDK Tools" Post, not "SDK"'s self!

Comment: Im a beginner at Android Developing, So I don't know what's the difference between "SDK" and "SDK Tools"! I only know "SDK Tools" is a small pack, having a few .exe programs. Can you tell me about these? :)

Comment: Try this location: C:/Users/USER/SDK
If you have a vpn connection, SDK Manager will show you the list of items you can access.
If you want to download manually, you'll need SDK Platform Tools and SDK Tools, both of which are required and you can find them in this [link](https://soft98.ir/mobile/13883-android-sdk.html).

Comment: Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8819545/12813115) to learn more about SDK Platform Tools and SDK Tools for Android

Comment: Did you mean I should move "..\AppData\Local\Sdk" Folder to "C:\Users\USER\SDK"? Whats requirements in this folder? Do I should create "emulator", "platform-tools", etc manually?

Comment: Where to extract "SDK Platform" and "SDK Tools" downloaded from soft98?

Comment: I only changed the "C:\Users\USER\SDK" Path to Android Studio. But it didn't differente! look at [this picture](https://i.imgur.com/FOFEHcm.png)